# Variable not redefining correctly in for loop (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I need to create a function that correctly computes E<sub>m</sub> as E<sub>m</sub> = 1 - mE

m-1

I'm having some issues figuring out why my variable isn't returning the correct values. Here is a summary of the problem I am tackling

Write a function called integration that takes as input the integer `m` and,
using the algorithm described below, returns the value of `E_m`. Make certain that you index this correctly, i.e. E<sub>0</sub> = 1 − 1/e
not E1

 = 1 − 1/e. Be very careful with how Python indexes if you try to do this as an indexed array.

```
Set E = 1 - 1/e
    for j = 1, ... , m do
        E = 1 - j*E
    end for
    return E
```

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
def integration(m):
  E_m = 1 - 1/np.e
  for j in range(m):
    E_m = 1 - j*E_m
  return E_m
```

My code, `if m > 0`, returns the wrong answer (for example `integration(1)` returns `1`, when it should be `1 - 1*(1-1/e)`). The text seems to indicate that I should use an array, but I don't see why I would need to. **Why isn't my code redefining my variable E_m correctly?** I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure if it's a problem with having the variable name in the redefinition or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python loops start with 0 and are non-inclusive. Try `range(1, m+1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it. I'm still trying to get used to this. I come from a c++ and java background, so trying to adjust to python's syntax has been confusing.

Comment: Python "loops" don't start with 0, a for-loop will loop through everything in an iterable. The iterable defined by `range` in the OP includes a zero.